# Remove characters from Text within a list - SharePoint 2016 onprem

Tags: calculated-column, sharepoint-on-prem, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to remove certain characters or only display certain characters within a list.
The source field is called [Issue Status] and created a calculated column with the following:

```
=LEFT([Issue Status],3)
```

However, this error appears: "The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported. "
Even when I try this following, still get the same error message!

```
=LEFT([Issue Status],LEN([Issue Status])-3)
```

Info: the issue status contains 6 characters in total.
However, the length of this may vary depending on other used words.

Whereas using the simple `=LEFT([Issue Statys])` works and shows only the 1st character. I am confused and now sure how to get this resolved.

UPDATE

The source type of the source column is [Choice] but I also tried it with another source column type [Single Line aka. Text]. and no luck.

Comment: What is the column type of the source column?

Comment: @Jerry_MSFT I was hopping it had to do something with the column type but nope. I just used another source column `[Title]` where the content type is `Single line of Text`. None of the above forumlas work apart from `=LEFT([Title])` which displays only the first character.

Comment: @Bucki Depending on your regional settings for the site you might have to use semicolon (;) instead of colon (,).

Comment: @Christoffer hahaaaaaaaaaa unbelieveable! the `;` has worked out. Wow, never knew that the regional settings does make a change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Christoffer

Because the regional settings is set to Germany, the formula did not work.
Instead of the `,` comma the semmycolon `;` must be used.

```
=LEFT([Issue Status];3)
```